# In linux, how to delete all files EXCEPT the pattern *.txt?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards

I know how to delete all `txt` file under current directory by `rm *.txt`.
Does anyone know how to delete all files in current directory EXCEPT `txt` file?

Comment: As always, test the given answers with a harmless command like `ls` before actually attempting to call `rm`.

Comment: ^ This guy doesn't like to live dangerously.. :)

Comment: ^ Guess who just did :facepalm: lol

Answer (score 205, accepted):

You can use `find`:

```
find . -type f ! -name '*.txt' -delete
```

Or bash's extended globbing features:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm *.!(txt)
```

Or in zsh:

```
setopt extendedglob
rm *~*.txt(.)
#  ||     ^^^ Only plain files
#  ||^^^^^ files ending in ".txt"
#  | \Except
#   \Everything
```

Comment: Some of these may need to be adapted depending on whether you have folders and what you want to do with them.

Comment: Shouldn't `*.!(txt)` be `!(*.txt)`?

Comment: @LauriRanta depends on what's in the folder, which we haven't gotten an answer to. It's fine as is if all the files have extensions, and `rm` would choke if there were folders.

Comment: I've got an issue with the brackets. When I use the globbing style in a bash script, it complains about a syntax error and the parentheses. However doing it from the CLI works.

Comment: `$ find . -type f ! -name "*.txt" | xargs rm`

Comment: @Ntwobike `xargs rm` will give error `rm: missing operand` when all files in the folder have `*.txt` extension (i.e. non-txt files were not found). This makes it impossible to use your variant in `.sh`-files when there are other commands after the failing one.

Comment: @izogfif check this `find . -type f ! -name "*.txt" | xargs -r rm` would work in GNU\xargs. BSD and UNIX xargs command may not have -r you have to check your local `man xargs`

Comment: This command does traverse directories further down, right?

Comment: @ECII the `find` command crawls the whole subtree, the globs do not.

Answer (score 24):

If you just want to delete all **files** except '*.txt' then you can use the following command:

`$ find . -type f ! -name "*.txt" -exec rm -rf {} \;`

but if you also want to delete **directories** along with the files then you can use this:

`$ find . ! -name "*.txt" -exec rm -r {} \;`

Answer (score 17):

there are many ways could do it.  but the most simple way would be (bash):

```
shopt -s extglob
rm !(*.txt)
```

Comment: How can i use this to specify multiple extensions?

Comment: `shopt -s extglob` is powerful. https://www.tecmint.com/delete-all-files-in-directory-except-one-few-file-extensions/ provides good examples. To delete all *except* certain extensions, `rm -v !(*.zip|*.odt)` works.

Answer (score 10):

You can use inverted grep and xargs

```
ls | grep -v .txt$| xargs rm
```

Comment: `ls | grep -v *.txt | xargs rm` works just as well

Comment: @phillipsk `grep -v *.txt` will work only if there's exactly one `.txt` file.  If there is none, `grep` will use `*.txt` as the pattern; if there's more than one, it will search for the first filename inside all of the other `.txt` files, ignoring the output from `ls`.  (Exact results may depend on the shell's glob options.)

Comment: `.txt$` will match strings ending with `txt` regardless of the dot. Because `grep` takes regular expression as parameter. So files `a.txt` and `aatxt` and `a-txt` will all be matched by this expression.  Correct expression should be `ls | grep -v \\.txt$ | xargs --no-run-if-empty rm`. For curious people: If you want to play around with the  expression safely use this  test expression `ls | grep \\.txt$ | xargs --no-run-if-empty echo` (note: there's no `-v` flag and `rm=>echo`).   Note2: you may have noticed double backslash. One is for regex, another is for bash to escape slash.

Answer (score 8):

One solution without `find`:

```
mv dir/*.txt otherdir/
rm -r dir
mv otherdir dir
```

This should work on all kind of shells.

Comment: I think this definitely has its place as it's the answer that an occasional user is most likely to remember in the long term.

Answer (score 5):

Simply do:

**`rm $(ls -I "*.txt" )`**  **#Deletes file type except *.txt**

Likewise, if need to delete "except one or more file type", do:

**`rm $(ls -I "*.txt" -I "*.pdf" )`**  #Deletes file types except *.txt & *.pdf

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange!  The `-I` option could be useful, but see [why not parse ls](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).  And what does the `| xargs` achieve?  Without any arguments, it just runs `echo` on all of its input.

Comment: What is `xargs` supposed to achieve?

Comment: Thanks, xargs was not useful in the above case, have corrected now.

Comment: This won't work if there are spaces in the file names. xargs would have been better. So `ls -1I '*.txt' | xargs -d'\n' rm`

Answer (score 1):

This works also to remove all **hidden (dot)** files and folders except the stated one (`.mydir`):

```
rm -rf $(ls -aI ".mydir")
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a modular bash function for this, based on a compilation of findings:

```bsh
rmexcept()
{
    files=()
    for pattern in "$@"
    do
        files+=(`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -iname "$pattern"`)
    done

    # filter for duplicates only when more than one pattern provided
    if (($# > 1))
    then
        printf "%s\n" ${files[@]} | sort | uniq -d | xargs rm
    else
        printf "%s\n" ${files[@]} | xargs rm
    fi
}
```

It is designed to work with multiple pattern arguments:

```bsh
rmexcept '*.tex' '*.pdf'
```

**NOTE**: The single quotes are necessary! Otherwise bash will expand
the wildcard and you will have a number of inputs equal to the matching
expansion, which causes every file to eventually repeat, and thus,
causes the function to delete everything!

If you don't want to remember this dangerous caveat (I don't), define
`rmexcept` as follows:

```bsh
rmexcept()
{
    files=()
    for pattern in "$@"
    do
        files+=(`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -iname "*$pattern"`)
    done

    # filter for duplicates only when more than one pattern provided
    if (($# > 1))
    then
        printf "%s\n" ${files[@]} | sort | uniq -d | xargs rm
    else
        printf "%s\n" ${files[@]} | xargs rm
    fi
}
```

And use without wildcards:

```bsh
rmexcept .tex .pdf
```

**NOTE**: You can still make a dangerous mistake by using a prefix `*`. I'll
keep thinking about how to improve this.

---

The way I put the `find` results in an array might not be best practice.
See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23356779/4682839) for more
details.

Answer (score -1):

```
ls |awk '!/\.txt$/{print "rm -rvf "$1}'| sh
```

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/86440) You’ve also got a wonderful command injection there — I hope you don’t care about any of the data on any systems on which you run similar commands, or that you don’t mind your personal data (SSH keys, GPG keys for example) being shared.